# How To Get Into D&D

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

Ok, so this is kind of a loaded question. My family thinks that D&D is stupid, so here I am, asking questions. Let it be known that I'm extremely new, and I'm talking about the board game D&D, the one you get around with your friends, and there is a dungeon master. And that right there is all I know about D&D.

How do I start playing D&D? What equipment do I need? I see booklets everywhere online, and I'm just not sure how to play. So... how do I play?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE and hopefully to the hobby! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!